# What is the Catholic view on wine consumption at the Wedding of Cana?

Tags: catholicism, weddings

The Catholic theologian & bishop Fulton Sheen wrote about (emphasis added) the [Marriage Feast at Cana](http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/cana.htm):

> Sometimes these Eastern marriages lasted for seven days, but in the
> case of the poorer people, for only two. Whatever was the case, at
> Cana, at some period of the entertainment the wine suddenly ran out.
> This was very embarrassing because of the passionate devotion of the
> Eastern people to hospitality, and also because of the mortification
> it offered to the wedded pair. It is permitted us to conjecture why
> the wine should have failed. This was a wine country, and it is very
> likely that the host laid in an abundant supply. **The explanation for
> the deficiency is probably the fact that Our Blessed Lord did not come
> alone. He brought with Him His disciples, and this apparently threw a
> heavy burden upon the store of wine.** Our Lord and His disciples had
> already been journeying for three days and had covered a distance of
> ninety miles. The disciples were thus so hungry, and so thirsty, that
> it was a wonder that the food did not give out as well as the wine.
> Since wine was a symbol of mirth and health to the people, it was
> important that their need be filled-as an old Hebrew proverb put it:
> "Where wine is wanting, doctors thrive."

What have other Catholic scholars written on the wine consumption at the wedding of Cana?

Comment: That was part of the plot of the episode of The Chosen with the Wedding at Cana too.

Comment: @PeterTurner Yes, the [reimagination episode](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11401082/) ([video here](https://watch.angelstudios.com/thechosen/watch?vid=S1:E5&ap=true)) is quite good and culturally authentic, serving multiple purposes too:  1. The reason why Jesus & Mary were there, 2. Origin of an apostle as food vendor becoming a witness to the account, 3. Using conversations in the wedding to thicken the characters of the apostles, etc.

Comment: John chapter 2, verse 2, tells us that both Jesus and his disciples were invited to the wedding. I don't quite see what Bishop Sheen means in suggesting they were not expected. Perhaps telling Jesus to bring his disciples was intended as a courtesy invitation, perhaps more turned up than were expected, perhaps they drank more wine than was expected. But John does say both Jesus and his disciples were invited.